# Android Logcat: showing my app's log messages after I re-plug in my phone after 10 or more minutes later?

Tags: android, eclipse, logcat

My Android app is successfully writing messages that I can view with Eclipse Logcat when my phone is plugged in with USB.

Now, when I'm out the the field, unplugged, my app is still producing `Log.i()` messages. However, when I plug my phone into my computer 10 or more minutes later, I cannot see those messages. Is there any way to view them in Eclipse Logcat? Or perhaps can I use `adb shell` to get on my phone and cat my messages from some file?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you need to go to "devices" view in Debug Window and click on your device, then suddenly all the logs are retrieved

Comment: I am able to see messages *after* I plug my phone in, but the problem is that I can't see messages that occurred several minutes ago.

Comment: All android devices i used so far (over 10 different) gave me ALL logs of the past xx minutes with this. Plug in, go to devices, click on the device and wait for logcat to finish with "downloading" all logs

Comment: Maybe my messages have expired. How can I check the value for "past XX minutes" setting and increase it to, say, 2 hours?